# mySQL UPDATE query wont work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

CODE:

```
$query="UPDATE americana SET 7='99' WHERE Bdate='2011-04-15'";
mysql_query($query);
```

NOTICE:7 and Bdate are column names.

> ERROR: Database query faild: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '7='99' WHERE
>   Bdate='2011-04-15'' at line 1.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Next time name that column Seven. And be sure to add a column OfNine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

enclose 7 in backticks `

```
$query="UPDATE americana SET `7`='99' WHERE Bdate='2011-04-15'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$query="UPDATE americana SET `7`='99' WHERE Bdate='2011-04-15'";
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

If 99 is an int you don't want quotes on that, mysql will see that as a string, refuse your insert and a kitten will die soemwhere.

```
$query="UPDATE americana SET `7`= 99 WHERE Bdate='2011-04-15'";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: @Shatki +1 For you! I stand corrected, it does indeed accept quotes around int.  I never put them when on mysql client. When I write small shell script I use sprintf, where types are enforced. But on MySQL client, ( and phpmyadmin ) , quotes or no quotes the ints are inserted. Thanks for correcting me, let's be happy that no kittens will die over this. :)